# Apache Zeppelin : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: core-site.xml not found in zeppelin webpage

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Currently, I'm setting up Zeppelin service. Zeppelin service daemon is able to start, but when I want to run my job from `http://servername:9080/#/notebook/notebook name`, then I have a runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: core-site.xml not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2869)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2838)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2715) .
```

Where should I define the path: #export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf/, if anyone knows in specific.

Zeppelin version: 0.9

Answer (score 0):

set HADOOP_CONF_DIR in zeppelin-env.sh